SignerError: keypair-pubkey mismatch
Im doing a random transaction where im buying a token with a Wrapped Solana Token Account
This account are under my main account (owner: my main account) and have balance
So with it, im performing it:
   swap_associated_token_address = Pubkey.from_string("address")   
   swap_tx = Transaction(recent_blockhash = block_hash) 
   instructions_swap = swap_inst(amount, 
                              wsol_kp.pubkey(),
                              swap_associated_token_address,
                              keys,
                              payer)
   swap_tx.add(set_compute_unit_limit(GAS_LIMIT))
   swap_tx.add(set_compute_unit_price(GAS_PRICE))
   swap_tx.add(instructions_swap)
   async_client = AsyncClient(ENDPOINT1,
                           commitment=Confirmed, 
                           timeout=30)
   txn = await async_client.send_transaction(swap_tx, 
                                          payer,
                                          wsol_kp)

In code:
payer are Keypair of main account
wsol_kp are Keypair of Wrapped Solana Token Account
amount are int()
keys are a dict
bloch_hash is a blockhash
This is what i get as response from the send_transaction:
SignerError: keypair-pubkey mismatch
What im missing?
I tried almost all searching solana cookbook and other places.

I solve it going here: https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/master/src/spl/token/core.py#L211
i saw they use Transaction(fee_payer=payer.pubkey()) so my swap_tx i add fee_payer and in send_transaction i just pass payer as a signer. Solved.
